# Round the nearest number

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I tried everything from round the nearest code. It is not the code that I'm looking for.
I tried round the nearest number 0.00750 to this 0.0080  How do around before decimal?

I want something like this:

```
0.0089 => 0.0090
0.0021 => 0.0020
0.1022 => 0.1020
```

Answer (score 2):

`math.h` contains `double round(double)` which will address the rounding part. To round to some number of decimal places try something like:

```
double roundPlaces(double d, int places)
{
   double factor = pow(10, places); // pow also in math.h

   return round(d * factor) / factor;
}
```

and then for your examples `roundPlaces(0.0089, 3)` produces `0.009`.

Answer (score 1):

you can make your own function using standard C function...

There's no round() in the C++ std library. You can write one yourself though:

```
double round(double d)
{
  return floor(d + 0.5);
}
```

(you can use C function in objective C )

Comment: Actually, `floor` is a C function, not C++ function.