# How do i round off the number ?? for example x=0.688773 and i want x=0.689

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

How do i round off the number ?? for example x=0.688773 and i want x=0.689

Comment: 7 questions asked and how many accepted? Tsk, tsk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round the nearest number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243437/round-the-nearest-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of number is it? If it's a float, then you can say:

```
myFloat = roundf(1000 * myFloat) / 1000.0;
```

If it's a double, use the round() function instead.

Comment: Found this on SO, that shows examples of  floor(), or ceil()   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c/1344261#1344261